# Trying to create slide show variants in shopify

Tags: javascript, java, json, shopify, shopify-template

I am new to shopify I am trying to create a website with a slide show variant. I have manage to write this code but I get the following error 
Line 247 — Liquid syntax error: 'schema' tag must not be nested inside other tags.

The code is meant to create the variant into a slide show using the app flex app.

Does anyone know were i am going wrong ?

```
 <!-- /templates/product.liquid -->
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product" id="ProductSection" data-section-id="{{ section.id }}" data-section-type="product-template" data-image-zoom-type="{{ section.settings.product_image_zoom_type }}" data-show-extra-tab="{{ section.settings.show_extra_tab }}" data-extra-tab-content="{{ section.settings.extra_tab_content }}" data-cart-enable-ajax="{{ settings.cart_enable_ajax }}" data-enable-history-state="true">

  <meta itemprop="name" content="{{ product.title }}">
  <meta itemprop="url" content="{{ shop.url }}{{ product.url }}">
  <meta itemprop="image" content="{{ product.featured_image.src | img_url: 'grande' }}">

  {% comment %}
    Get first variant in stock, or deep linked one
  {% endcomment %}
  {% assign current_variant = product.selected_or_first_available_variant %}
  {%- assign featured_image = current_variant.featured_image | default: product.featured_image -%}

  <div class="grid product-single">

    <div class="grid__item medium-up--one-half">
      {% for image in product.images %}
        {% capture img_id %}ProductImage-{{ image.id }}{% endcapture %}
        {% capture wrapper_id %}ProductImageWrapper-{{ image.id }}{% endcapture %}
        {%- assign img_url = image | img_url: '1x1' | replace: '_1x1.', '_{width}x.' -%}

        {% include 'image-style' with image: image, width: 720, height: 600, small_style: true, wrapper_id: wrapper_id, img_id: img_id %}

        <div id="{{ wrapper_id }}" class="product-single__featured-image-wrapper supports-js{% unless featured_image == image %} hidden{% endunless %}" data-image-id="{{ image.id }}">
          <div class="product-single__photos" data-image-id="{{ image.id }}" style="padding-top:{{ 1 | divided_by: image.aspect_ratio | times: 100}}%;">
            <img id="{{ img_id }}"
                 class="product-single__photo lazyload{% unless featured_image == image %} lazypreload{% endunless %}{% if section.settings.product_image_zoom_type == 'lightbox' %} lightbox{% endif %}"
                 {% if section.settings.product_image_zoom_type == 'zoom-in' %} data-zoom="{{ image | img_url: '1024x1024' }}"{% endif %}
                 src="{{ image | img_url: '200x200' }}"
                 data-src="{{ img_url }}"
                 data-widths="[180, 360, 470, 600, 750, 940, 1080, 1296, 1512, 1728, 2048]"
                 data-aspectratio="{{ image.aspect_ratio }}"
                 data-sizes="auto"
                 alt="{{ image.alt | escape }}">
          </div>
          {% if product.compare_at_price_max > product.price %}
            <span class="badge badge--sale"><span>{{ 'products.product.on_sale' | t }}</span></span>
          {% endif %}
        </div>
      {% endfor %}

      <noscript>
        <img src="{{ featured_image | img_url: 'grande' }}" alt="{{ featured_image.alt | escape }}">
      </noscript>

      {% if product.images.size > 1 %}
        <ul class="product-single__thumbnails grid grid--uniform" id="ProductThumbs">

          {% case product.images.size %}
            {% when 2 %}
              {% assign thumbnail_width = 'small--one-half medium-up--push-one-sixth medium-up--one-third' %}
            {% when 4 %}
              {% assign thumbnail_width = 'small--one-half medium-up--one-quarter' %}
            {% else %}
              {% assign thumbnail_width = 'small--one-third medium-up--one-third' %}
          {% endcase %}

          {% for image in product.images %}
            <li class="grid__item {{ thumbnail_width }}">
              <a href="{{ image.src | img_url: 'grande' }}" class="product-single__thumbnail" data-image-id="{{ image.id }}">
                <img src="{{ image.src | img_url: 'compact' }}" alt="{{ image.alt | escape }}">
              </a>
            </li>
          {% endfor %}

        </ul>
      {% endif %}

      {% if section.settings.product_image_zoom_type == 'lightbox' %}
        <ul class="gallery hidden">
          {% for image in product.images %}
            <li data-image-id="{{ image.id }}" class="gallery__item" data-mfp-src="{{ image | img_url: '2048x2048' }}"></li>
          {% endfor %}
        </ul>
      {% endif %}
    </div>

    <div class="grid__item medium-up--one-half{% if product.images.size == 0%} medium-up--push-one-half{% endif %}">
      <div class="product-single__meta small--text-center">
        <h1 class="product-single__title" itemprop="name">{{ product.title }}</h1>

        {% if section.settings.vendor_show %}
          <p class="product-single__vendor" itemprop="brand">{{ product.vendor }}</p>
        {% endif %}

        <div itemprop="offers" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">
          <meta itemprop="priceCurrency" content="{{ cart.currency.iso_code }}">

          <link itemprop="availability" href="http://schema.org/{% if current_variant.available %}InStock{% else %}OutOfStock{% endif %}">

          <p class="product-single__prices">
            {% if product.compare_at_price_max > product.price %}
              <span id="ComparePriceA11y" class="visually-hidden">{{ 'products.product.sale_price' | t }}</span>
            {% else %}
              <span class="visually-hidden">{{ 'products.product.regular_price' | t }}</span>
            {% endif %}
            <span id="ProductPrice" class="product-single__price" itemprop="price" content="{{ current_variant.price | divided_by: 100.00 }}">
              {{ current_variant.price | money }}
            </span>

            {% if product.compare_at_price_max > product.price %}
              <span id="PriceA11y" class="visually-hidden">{{ 'products.product.regular_price' | t }}</span>
              <s class="product-single__price--compare" id="ComparePrice">
                {{ current_variant.compare_at_price | money }}
              </s>
            {% endif %}

            {% include 'product-unit-price', variant: current_variant, available: true %}
          </p>

          {%- if shop.taxes_included or shop.shipping_policy.body != blank -%}
            <div class="product-single__policies rte">
              {%- if shop.taxes_included -%}
                {{ 'products.product.include_taxes' | t }}
              {%- endif -%}
              {%- if shop.shipping_policy.body != blank -%}
                {{ 'products.product.shipping_policy_html' | t: link: shop.shipping_policy.url }}
              {%- endif -%}
            </div>
          {%- endif -%}
          {%- assign productClasses = 'product-form' -%}
          {%- if product.has_only_default_variant -%}
            {%- assign productClasses = productClasses | append: ' product-form--default-variant-only' -%}
          {%- endif -%}

          {% form 'product', product, class: productClasses %}
            <select name="id" id="ProductSelect-{{ section.id }}" class="product-single__variants">
              {% for variant in product.variants %}
                {% if variant.available %}
                  <option {% if variant == product.selected_or_first_available_variant %} selected="selected" {% endif %} data-sku="{{ variant.sku }}" value="{{ variant.id }}">{{ variant.title }} - {{ variant.price | money_with_currency }}</option>
                {% else %}
                  <option disabled="disabled">
                    {{ variant.title }} - {{ 'products.product.sold_out' | t }}
                  </option>
                {% endif %}
              {% endfor %}
            </select>

            {% if section.settings.product_quantity_enable %}
              <div class="product-single__quantity">
                <label for="Quantity">{{ 'products.product.quantity' | t }}</label>
                <input type="number" id="Quantity" name="quantity" value="1" min="1">
              </div>
            {% endif %}

            <div class="product-single__cart-submit-wrapper{% if section.settings.enable_payment_button %} product-single__shopify-payment-btn{% endif %}{% if section.settings.add_to_cart_width == 'full_width' %} product-form--full{% endif %}">
              <button type="submit" name="add" id="AddToCart" class="btn product-single__cart-submit{% if section.settings.add_to_cart_width == 'full_width' %} btn--full{% endif %}{% if section.settings.enable_payment_button %} shopify-payment-btn btn--secondary{% endif %}" data-cart-url="{{ routes.cart_url }}">
                <span id="AddToCartText">{{ 'products.product.add_to_cart' | t }}</span>
              </button>
              {% if section.settings.enable_payment_button %}
                {{ form | payment_button }}
              {% endif %}
            </div>

          {% endform %}

        </div>

        {% if section.settings.product_description_position == 'right' %}
          {%- assign position = 'right' -%}
          {% include 'product-description' %}
        {% endif %}

        {% if section.settings.social_sharing_products %}
          {% include 'social-sharing', share_title: product.title, share_permalink: product.url, share_image: product %}
        {% endif %}
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>

  {% if section.settings.product_description_position == 'below' %}
    {%- assign position = 'below' -%}
    {% include 'product-description' %}
  {% endif %}
</div>

{% unless product == empty %}
  <script type="application/json" id="ProductJson-{{ section.id }}">
    {{ product | json }}
  </script>
{% endunless %}

<script>
  // Override default values of shop.strings for each template.
  // Alternate product templates can change values of
  // add to cart button, sold out, and unavailable states here.
  window.productStrings = {
    addToCart: {{ 'products.product.add_to_cart' | t | json }},
    soldOut: {{ 'products.product.sold_out' | t | json }},
    unavailable: {{ 'products.product.unavailable' | t | json }}
  }
  {% if product.variants.size > 1 %}
<script>
(function($) {
  var variantImages = {},
    thumbnails,
    variant,
    variantImage,
    variantImage_count = 0;
    //produce mapping between variant image and options
    {% for variant in product.variants %}
       variant = {{ variant | json }};
       if ( typeof variant.featured_image !== 'undefined' && variant.featured_image !== null ) {
         variantImage =  variant.featured_image.src.split('?')[0].replace(/http(s)?:/,'');
         variantImages[variantImage] = variantImages[variantImage] || {};
         {% for option in product.options %}
           {% assign option_value = variant.options[forloop.index0] %}
           {% assign option_key = 'option-' | append: forloop.index0 %}
           if (typeof variantImages[variantImage][{{ option_key | json }}] === 'undefined') {
             variantImages[variantImage][{{ option_key | json }}] = {{ option_value | json }};
           }
           else {
             var oldValue = variantImages[variantImage][{{ option_key | json }}];
             if ( oldValue !== null && oldValue !== {{ option_value | json }} )  {
               variantImages[variantImage][{{ option_key | json }}] = null;
             }
           }
         {% endfor %}
         variantImage_count++;
       }
    {% endfor %}

    $(function() {

      if (variantImage_count > 0) {
        $('select.single-option-selector').change(function() {
          var selected_color = $(this).val();
          thumbnails = $('.flex-control-thumbs img').each(function(index, el) {
            var image = $(el).attr('src').split('?')[0].replace(/(_thumb\.)|(_small\.)|(_compact\.)|(_medium\.)|(_large\.)|(_grande\.)/,'.');
            if (typeof variantImages<div class="full"></div> !== 'undefined') {
              if(selected_color == variantImages<div class="full"></div>['option-0']) {
                //only check against the first option ['option-0'], which is Color (in my case)
                $('.flexslider').flexslider(index);
              }
            }
              });
        });
      }

    });
})(jQuery);
</script>

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The [`{% schema %}` tag](https://shopify.dev/docs/themes/sections/content-schema) was introduced with Shopify's "[sectioned themes](https://www.shopify.ca/partners/blog/introducing-sections-for-shopify-themes)". I can see that your shopify theme is using "Sections", because of all the reference to the `section` variable in your code!

Since searching for `{% schema %}` within your question code doesn't return any results, I have to conclude the syntax error is originating in a different file. (Probably one including your `product.liquid` file with a [`{% section 'product' %}` directive](https://shopify.dev/tutorials/develop-theme-use-sections#static-and-dynamic-sections).

In the Shopify theme docs about "[Using theme sections](https://shopify.dev/tutorials/develop-theme-use-sections#using-section-schema-tags)", we see that the `{% schema %}` tag lives in templates that are inside of the `sections/` folder in your theme's directory structure. In this case, I'd **expect to find the nested tag causing the syntax error within `sections/product.liquid`.**